# multilanguage plural localization

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, nslocalizedstring

I'm implementing localization in my iOS application and I got stuck with plural forms.

I have two languages in my application.

When I've created *Localizable.strings* files they got language assigned to them so each file has one language.

Now when I created *Localizable.stringsdict* so I could handle plural forms it doesn't seem to be assigned to any language so I don't know how to handle different languages here.

Can anybody please help me understand this?

**Edited**:
I'm not sure if I can provide any code that would help but let's say my *Localizable.stringsdict* file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NumberOfMessages</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
        <string>%#@value@</string>
        <key>value</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>d</string>
            <key>one</key>
            <string>You have a new message.</string>
            <key>other</key>
            <string>You have %d new messages.</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Where should I put translations for another language?

Comment: Provide code so we can help

Comment: I have edited the main question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the file in the Xcode navigator and open the right-hand pane:

[image]

Click the "Localize..." button at the bottom to localize this file.

If you've localized things in this project before, there will be options to add it to each language in your project. If you haven't localized anything, go to the main projects settings and add Localizations:

[image]

When you localize files, copies will be put into the various `*.lproj` directories in your project.

Comment: It works, that's exactly what I needed! Thank you very much